# Rpi2 image on a Rpi3: Module spi-bcm2708 not found

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-2, pi-3, spi

I was using a RPi2 with an RFID-RC522 Board. Now I bougth an new RPi3 because of the included WLAN. I am trying to use the same image I use with my RPi2 in my RPi3 now. But I encounter a very frustrating problem.

If I just take the sd card from the RPi2 and plug it into my RPi3 every thing works fine except the included WLAN. But since I want to use it I run updates,upgrades,dist-upgrade rpi-upgrade.
Now my WLAN works but when I try to enable SPI over raspi-config I get the Error: Module spi-bcm2708 not found. I read that there was a switch to bcm2835 but I don´t know if my libs work with the bcm2835 instead of the bcm2708.

My libs:
https://github.com/lthiery/SPI-Py
https://github.com/mxgxw/MFRC522-python

It would be really nice if somebody can help me to get the included WLAN to work on an older kernel-version or get the libs working on the newest with the spi-bcm2835

Comment: You need recent kernel for WiFi. Current is  `4.1.19-v7+`. NOTE you should NOT run `rpi-upgrade` which can install untested software (although I don't think this is the cause of your problem). A number of people (myself included) have had difficulties with `RFID-RC522` on Jessie. I have seen some reports of success but they didn't work for me. I admit I haven't made a serious attempt to debug the software.